# There are 15 cows and 20 sheep. Given a condition, how many ways are there to pick 4 animals?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to pick 4 animals if there is a cow and a calf in the 15 cows. If the mother cow or calf is picked, they must both be picked.

My work: 13 cows and 20 sheep left to choose from. Suppose the cow and calf are picked then there are (33C2) to pick 2 more animals. So (33C2) ways to pick 4 animals such that if a mother cow is picked so is it’s calf. (Only one of this pair exists out of 15 cows).

Comment: You also need to consider the case when both mother and calf are not picked in the group of $4$.

Comment: What is your attempt for the case in which neither the cow nor the calf is selected?

Comment: Would it be 33C4?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Look back in time, when the calf was unborn. It is easy to see that our initial problem is equivalent to count the number of ways to choose 4 animals among 13+1 pregnant cows and 20 sheep, which is clearly ${13+1+20\choose 4}=46376$.